# Google Speech to Text API gives different results locally than the online demo

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-speech

6 second mp3 audio file([download](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=53555918937931657345))
First tested directly on https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/ and the response was as expected.

**"hello brother how are you doing I'm doing really well hope mom is doing well"**

Then I created firebase Function(see code below):

```
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech').v1p1beta1
exports.speechToText = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Creates a client
    const client = new speech.SpeechClient()
    const gcsUri = `gs://xxxxx.appspot.com/speech.mp3`

    const config = {
      encoding: 'MP3',
      languageCode: 'en-US',
      enableAutomaticPunctuation: false,
      enableWordTimeOffsets: false,
    }
    const audio = {
      uri: gcsUri,
    }

    const request = {
      config: config,
      audio: audio,
    }

    // Detects speech in the audio file
    const [response] = await client.recognize(request)
    const transcription = response.results
      .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
      .join('\n')
    console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`)
    res.send({ response })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error:', error)
    res.status(400).send({
      error,
    })
  }
})
```

And I get the following INCORRECT response:

**"hello brother, how are you doing hope all is doing well"**

**UPDATE:**
The same INCORRECT response is received when running Locally. So Cloud Functions are not the issue.

**UPDATE #2:**
setting the `model:'video'` OR `model:'phone_call'` in config
solved the issue. i.e

```
    const config = {
      encoding: 'MP3',
      languageCode: 'en-US',
      enableAutomaticPunctuation: false,
      enableWordTimeOffsets: false,
      model: 'phone_call',
    }
```

Comment: It seems unlikely that Google Cloud Functions is causing this problem. Can you reproduce it by just running the code in a local Node.js script? If so, you can rule out GCF.

Comment: frank, you are right. its the same incorrect response running it locally.

Comment: Cool. Well at least in that it rules out Cloud Functions as a factor. If the demo results in something different, it'd either have to use a different version of the API, or different parameters.

Comment: Ah, I just see that you found the solution, which was indeed parameters. You should post that as an answer, as it may well be useful for folks in the same situation in the future.

Comment: i am having the same issue. but i cannot seem to solve it, i am not using the beta though so i do not know if that can be affecting the outcome. I am very  frustrated and about to pose my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting the `model:'video'` OR `model:'phone_call'` in `config` solved the issue. i.e

```
const config = {
 encoding: 'MP3',
 languageCode: 'en-US',
 enableAutomaticPunctuation: false,
 enableWordTimeOffsets: false,
 model: 'phone_call', 
}
```

I suppose the `default` model doesn't work on certain type of audio.